# "Missing Quartz Composition" displayed on TotalTerminal

Tags: terminal, macos

I started using [TotalTermianl](http://totalterminal.binaryage.com/) on Mountain Lion.

But the background have `Missing Quartz Composition` error.

I have found some people had the same as mine [here](https://getsatisfaction.com/binaryage/topics/_missing_quartz_composition_error_displayed_on_totalterminal)

Do anyone know how to fix it??

Comment: The fix mentioned in the linked article doesn't work for you?

Comment: Is there a solution for the link according to the article?

Comment: look at the last comment in https://getsatisfaction.com/binaryage/topics/_missing_quartz_composition_error_displayed_on_totalterminal

Comment: Oh.  I've downloaded xcode.  but I can't find `/Developer/Library/Quartz Composer/Examples/` these directories in my laptop.

Comment: You have to install Quartz Composer from the developer website, the examples are in `/Applications/Xcode Utilities/Quartz Composer.app/Contents/Resources/Examples` then.

Comment: And did you install the latest version of TotalTerminal (1.3)?

Comment: OK.  Now I have installed Xcode and also installed Quartz Composer from the developer website so far.  so what's next, making my own Quartz Composer??  What's the Quartz Composer exactly for, I have no idea what I'm dealing with??  By the way, my TotalTerminal is in the latest version.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4474/discussion-between-lijung-and-patrix)

Answer (score 1):

In Mavericks, transitions can be found under

```
/Applications/Quartz\ Composer.app/Contents/Resources/Examples/Graphic\ Transitions/
```

Comment: How does knowing this help to solve the OPs problem?